# Why the same code give different result in jsfiddl?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn puzzle game Javascript by studying Codepen examples, but every time I paste the code to another place, it all changes. To show you what I mean, I took the html, css, and JS from this pen and pasted it directly to a JSFiddle, which got me a broken result. this is the example http://codepen.io/Dubi_Kaufmann/pen/GktqH and btw i added JQuery code but it didnt work :( help

Comment: where is the JSFiddle.  Is this link you post safe?

Comment: I'll bet you forgot to select one of the `No wrap` options in jsfiddle.

Comment: wait lemme link it to you

Comment: @Teemu He said he's going to add it.

Comment: `Math.random()` gives different results for the same code :p

Comment: i copied the same codepen to jsfiddl

Comment: should i delete the math random :P?

Comment: where is the link for the fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w3zL2/

Comment: srry for being late thats the link :P

Comment: @AliAbdulBasit You have to add a jQuery library (and other used libraries) to your jsFiddle, now it says "`No library, pure JS`".

Comment: i added that but still dont work man :(

Comment: @AliAbdulBasit [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/A3cFd/) it works, you've only just some timing problems at jsFiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to select to place your script in the `<body>` element, under the nowrap option. As [Barmar has very helpfully pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777857/why-the-same-code-give-different-result-in-jsfiddl/20777900?noredirect=1#comment31144371_20777900), the reason is that by wrapping the code you are not making the functions in the JS global, therefore they will be inaccessible from the HTML.

I have copied the code over to a new Fiddle, and it works - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/A8Hjw/

Also, you will probably have to add Prefixfree.js in order for CSS3 transforms to work in some browsers. I have linked to a CDN-hosted version available at [//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js) (`//` without any prefix so that it will be compatible over both HTTP and HTTPS connections).

Comment: I played a little with that option, and it doesn't make any difference. It works regardless

Comment: Maybe he just forgot to add the external resources of prefixfree.min.js

Comment: The `no wrap` option is needed because the HTML has inline Javascript calls. When you wrap in jsfiddle, all the JS is inside an anonymous function, so the function names are not in the global scope.

Comment: @alkis Oh yes, that, too. I think I forgot to mention :) thanks!

Comment: I haven't used jsfiddle a lot, but you might have saved me from some serious frustration in the future :P . Upvoted of course.

Comment: @alkis When I discovered CodePen, I never turned back ;) (mostly because it supported pre-processing languages for CSS) And thanks for the +1! I'm not sure how I might have saved you, but I'm glad it did... even if it's in the smallest, most insignificant sense.

Comment: I'll start using that then. Thnx!